# Clerk middleware afterAuth(auth, req), auth status is always signed-out

Tags: next.js, middleware, clerk

Hello guys I have some trouble on setup clerk in Nextjs14. My middleware contain

```
...
afterAuth(auth, req, _) {}
...
```

but when i try to call auth.userId it contain null, and redirect to sign-in route, but when it is arrive in /sign-in route, it redirect to root route. So middleware didn't detect userId, session, and etc, but  component detect if it was signed in.

i try to console log the auth, it shows:

```
{
  sessionClaims: null,
  sessionId: null,
  session: null,
  userId: null,
  user: null,
  actor: null,
  orgId: null,
  orgRole: null,
  orgSlug: null,
  orgPermissions: null,
  organization: null,
  getToken: [Function: getToken],
  has: [Function: has],
  debug: [Function],
  isPublicRoute: false,
  isApiRoute: false
}
```

i already followed clerk tutorial, I use src folder so, i placed my middleware in

/src/middlware.ts

and i used trpc.

can someone have same issue as i am?

Answer (score 0):

If helpful to others in the future: if your `CLERK_SECRET_KEY` is wrong for the given environment, it will have a null `auth` in the middleware

This ends up looking like an infinite redirect after login since it keeps redirecting back to sign-in route with `auth` being null

You can set `debug` true in the middleware and look at the errors in the logs and it'll help clarify

> The provided Clerk Secret Key is invalid. Make sure that your Clerk Secret Key is correct.

See https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware for more